# How to center ngb-timepicker in a col-nn

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular8

I have a time picker component in Angular 8, with bootstrap 4. I'm trying to center a `ngb-timepicker` in a `col-12` inside this component.

```
<div class="row pickerContainer"> 
  <div class="col-12 pickerCenterer">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
    <hr>
    <pre>Selected time: {{time | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>

.pickerContainer{
  text-align:center;
}
.pickerCenterer{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

This results with text being centered, but not the time picker. Stackblitz example here: https://cqutyi.run.stackblitz.io/

[image]

How do I center the time-picker itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **row** class instead of col-12 like below.

```
<div class="row pickerContainer"> 
  <div class="row pickerCenterer">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
    <hr>
    <pre>Selected time: {{time | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzvzn7